# add relation that depends on the content of a table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So i have the following tables: 'order', 'comments', 'personnel' and 'contactperson'

What i want is to get all the orders with their comments and thats comment's author

so i do this to get the comments:

```
Order::with('comments')->get();
```

No problem here. But how can i get the author of those comments.

The Order table has the following fields:
id_author -> int
fk_author -> enum('personnel','contactperson')

Now depending on the fk_author field, the author should be fetched from the personnel table or the contactperson table.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [polymorphic relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations). On your orders table, you will want to rename your columns to fit what Eloquent expects author_id, author_type instead of id_author and fk_author